# JavaScript code issue : I am converting object to array

Tags: javascript

I am converting JavaScript object to array but in result I am getting one `null`

here my code

```
<div id="a"></div>

Object.prototype.toArray = function(){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in this) {
        arr.push(this[i]);        
    }
    return arr;
} 

var providers = {
            facebooklike: "Facebook Like",
            facebookrecommend : "Facebook Recommend",
            facebooksend : "Facebook Send",
            twittertweet : "Twitter Tweet",
            linkedinshare : "LinkedIn Share",
            linkedinrecommend : "LinkedIn Recommend",
            googleplusplusone : "Google+ +1",
            googleplusshare : "Google+ Share"
        };

var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(providers.toArray());
```

My result is

> ["Facebook Like","Facebook Recommend","Facebook Send","Twitter
>   Tweet","LinkedIn Share","LinkedIn Recommend","Google+ +1","Google+
>   Share",null]

Here is fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/govindmalviya/Fy26h/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `hasOwnProperty` check.

```
for (var i in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        arr.push(this[i]);
    }        
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why it is getting extra property in for in loop

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya And you should know the null comes from the key `toArray`, and the last element in the result array is a function, which caused null when do `JSON.stringify` :)

Answer (score 4):

Add check for own properties (not inherited from the Object proptotype):

```
Object.prototype.toArray = function(){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i))
            arr.push(this[i]);        
    }
    return arr;
}
```